# Is Saddam Hussein Canadian or Danish?

Tags: south-park

When we see Saddam Hussein his head, besides being a photo, is similar to a Canadian or Danish head which are shown to be flappy Pac-Man-like heads (Danish we see this when they appear in the episode where Canada Goes on Strike)

Now I am wondering if this means (*South Park* wise) Saddam Hussein is related to Canada or Denmark in some way despite that is real life counterpart having been born in Iraq

Comment: This could maybe be tackled by first asking how Danes are related to Canadians to begin with and if that kind of animation is not maybe generally reserved for other nationalities (though, we've seen Japanese and Chinese with a more elaborate head animation, but those are different ethnicities altogether). Though, I guess the use of a stock photo is more practically related to his head animation.

Comment: Mel Gibson is also photographic, but not Canadian. Also the Danes in S20 have normal heads.

Comment: When did they have Danes on the show? I’m pretty sure Canadians were first to appear like that by a long way.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat https://southpark.fandom.com/wiki/Denmark

Comment: It’d be interesting if there was a over arching art theme for Saddam, his voice is even ‘canadian’ like T&P, on top of the separated head art style. However the Danes were the european canadian ripoff/equivalent, so their art style was supposed be similar to canadians as per the joke. Saddam may very well be canadian!

Comment: Have we seen any other Iraqis in South Park?  Maybe Iraq is just another country to get this animation style.